# Прибавлять ID при отправке с формы

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

```
<?php
//Если переменная SCRIPT передана
if (isset($_POST["Name"])) {
    //Вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `support` (`id`, `Name`, `Email`, `vk`, `Text`) 
                        VALUES ('".$_POST['id']."','".$_POST['Name']."','".$_POST['Email']."','".$_POST['vk']."','".$_POST['Text']."')");
    //Если вставка прошла успешно
    if ($sql) {
        echo "<p>Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Подскажите как сделать чтобы при отправке с формы постоянно прибавлялся идентификатор 'id' в бд у меня поле id INT а все остальные text

Answer (score 1):

Убрать поле `id` из запроса, и если в БД `auto_increment` отмечен в поле `id`, то все само будет добавляться.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `support` (`Name`, `Email`, `vk`, `Text`) 
                        VALUES ('".$_POST['Name']."','".$_POST['Email']."','".$_POST['vk']."','".$_POST['Text']."')");
```

Answer (score 1):

В бд сделать поле id автоинкриментом, и потом при добавлении записи в таблицу (при запросе) передавать запись id как `null`.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнении к ответу @Kosta-B 
Получить ID только-что вставленной записи 
[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id)
Но уже давно надо переходить на >php7 т.к. выше PHP5.5 MySQL depercated и, соответственно, метод будет отличаться [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте таким образом.

```
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `support` (`id`, `Name`, `Email`, `vk`, `Text`) 
                    VALUES ('".$id"','".$_POST['Name']."','".$_POST['Email']."','".$_POST['vk']."','".$_POST['Text']."')");
```